# Are the Stack Overflow blog and the Stack Exchange blog the same blog?

Tags: support, blog

I found that [(SE blog) Announcing The Launch Of Meta Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/) and [(SO blog) Announcing The Launch Of Meta Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/) are absolutely the same, right down to the comments. No redirect, just duplication. Why?

Comment: Perhaps it is a result of overlap? Although I think there is something interesting in that the link to the Stack Exchange blog goes to blog.stackoverflow.com and not blog.stackexchange.com (which do have different content).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the exact same blog post (and the exact same blog), just available at two different URLs.

In fact, if you look at the HTML source for either of the pages, you'll find the tag:

```html
<link rel='canonical' href='http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/' />
```

That tag is there to tell search engines that the *official* URL of this blog post is the one with the host name blog.stackoverflow.com; the blog.stackexchange.com address is just an alias.

---

**Update:** As of December 2015 (at least), blog.stackexchange.com now redirects to blog.stackoverflow.com, probably due to the recent company-wide [name change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) / [rebranding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270037/shouldnt-the-terms-of-service-of-use-stack-overflow-inc/270038#270038) of Stack Exchange, Inc. to Stack Overflow.