# The community bulletin on sites other than Stack Overflow do not link to the lastest blog post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, blog, community-bulletin

The Winter Bash 2014 [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) is only showing on Stack Overflow's Community Bulletin for me. I've checked ell.SE, meta.SE, and lifehacks.SE, and it's not featured on those sites, so I'm assuming it's not featured anywhere but on SO and meta.SO.

Shouldn't it be featured for all sites, or at least all sites that participated in the Winter bash?

Comment: It takes time for it to propagate through the network. PS @nicael the SO blog is the same as the SE blog.

Comment: Damn, @ani I remember I even [asked a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230057/are-the-stack-overflow-blog-and-the-stack-exchange-blog-the-same-blog) about those blogs :D but I thought that it is somehow possible to make this blog visible only on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of a minute or two ago, the post is featured on other Community Bulletins:

[image: ELL]

It just takes a little while for all 130+ sites to get updated.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/