# Shouldn't the Terms of Service use Stack Overflow, Inc.?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, legal, terms-of-service

The [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) still uses the term Stack Exchange, Inc.

However, I believe that the name is now Stack Overflow, Inc. , so I believe that should be changed to that. It is weird to have the wrong name in a legal document.

<sub><sub>Yes, I actually read the Terms of Service. You should also do that.</sub></sub>

Comment: Wait, you actually *read* the Terms of Service? What is this madness? :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *legal* company name is still Stack Exchange, Inc.

Though, we are now using Stack Overflow as our *brand* / [trade name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_name).

Comment: Okay, but shouldn't it read Stack Exchange Inc. (“Stack Overflow”) in that case? (That is actually quite confusing, isn't it?)

Comment: Legal documents tend do be confusing, don't they?

Comment: @wythagoras As I understand it, it's one of these deals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_name.