# Why is the company email still "at stackoverflow"

Tags: discussion

I got a mail from the Stack Exchange Travel Site that I am one of the top users this month.

In the email, I saw:

> Email us directly at team@stackoverflow.com any time

Why are they putting `@stackoverflow.com` there instead of `@stackexchange.com`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is how the company is named see: https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/

Comment: @rene _Legally_ the company is named Stack Exchange, Inc. "Stack Overflow" is a "doing business as" (trade/brand) name. (See Oded's answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270037), which may very well be a duplicate.)

Answer (score 4):

The company is still branded Stack Overflow, although the official company name is [Stack Exchange Inc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa/277370#comment898595_277370).

They've used the Stack Exchange *brand* for a while, but [in 2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) they reverted to Stack Overflow again. In all that time, the email addresses never changed. They still use the same domain as that they did on day 1, when there was just Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, both domains work for email. someone@stackoverflow.com and someone@stackexchange.com will arrive to the same person in the same mailbox (assuming it isn't a group email address).

Comment: Okay, but you use `@stackoverflow.com` to communicate to the outside world. That is does work is nice, but undocumented, right? @Oded

Comment: More often than not, yes, the `@stackoverflow.com` - it is the better known domain. I don't know if we ever documented how this works.