# Add a note to the blog post on the company "name change" that the legal name is still "Stack Exchange, Inc."

Tags: feature-request, blog, company, site-name

The legal company name has been, for many years, "Stack Exchange, Inc.". However, in September 2015, a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/) was published that stated that the name was being changed to "Stack Overflow". This was later clarified as a [rebranding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270037/shouldnt-the-terms-of-service-use-stack-overflow-inc/270038#270038), not an official change to the legal name.

Still, we get a lot of confused users referring to the company as "Stack Overflow, Inc." because the blog post **very strongly implies** that the legal name was changed.

Can a note please be added to the bottom of the blog post, clarifying that the "name change" mentioned there is to the brand, not the legal name, and that the legal name is still "Stack Exchange, Inc."?

(Side note: the company *can't* be named "Stack Overflow, Inc." because another company took that name first, so in its early days it was called "Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc.".)

Comment: It's confusing to read that blog post and still see "site design / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc" at the bottom of each page. I was thinking that might have been an oversight, and a clarification on the blog post would have helped to make it clear it isn't.