# Some improvement suggestions for the Reputation value change email

Tags: feature-request, reputation, email

Yesterday, I received an email about the [reputation value change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/).

When viewing the mail in the standard iOS Mail app (on an iPhone 7 Plus, if it matters), the gray background isn't as wide as it should be, which makes the footer look kinda awful:

[image]
[image]

Second, "across Stack Overflow" is a bit confusing. It could imply that only a [single site](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be affected. I understand you want to use Stack Overflow as a [brand name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270038/295232), which is why the email isn't titled "Reputation values are changing across Stack Exchange", but in the future, can you at least add the word "network"? E.g.

> Reputation values are changing across the Stack Overflow network

Comment: Checking my email... where is it? I don't see one.

Comment: It might depend on your email preferences if you get one. It was sent (to me) yesterday 19:29 UTC.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I had *Features & Announcements* disabled in `/users/email/settings/<user id>`.